# Python Open CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'd like to open a csv called x with the file name "blah.csv" in a folder.

```
import csv
def amread(x):
    with open('x', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
            return;
```

> amread() returns name blah.csv is not defined

due to the lack of clarity, here is a full unedited quotation from the interaction pane:

```
>>> import csv
>>> def amread(x):
...     with open('x', newline='') as f:
...             reader = csv.reader(f)
...             for row in reader:
...                     print(row)
...                     return;
... 
>>> amread(blah.csv)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'blah' is not defined
```

Comment: Needs `import csv`?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? is this the full code? Python's variables are case sensitive and your code doesn't have a variable named `CSV`.

Comment: that is not the answer. the csv library to which zengr posted a link contains a function called 'csv.reader'

Comment: Um... your code was missing the `import csv`?

Comment: that is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> amread(blah.csv)
```

This looks for a name in the python namespace `blah.csv`.  You have no variable or parameter with this name, which causes the error "name blah.csv is not defined".

Assuming what you want is to open a file that is actually named blah.csv, you would pass that name as a string:

```
>>> amread('blah.csv')
```

Comment: ...and then change `with open('x', ....` to `with open(x, ...)` as otherwise you're just opening the file named 'x', regardless of what you pass in.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is pretty good at this, I generally use read_csv.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

from dave costa's answer, which is correct:

> > > amread(blah.csv)
> > >       This looks for a name in the python namespace blah.csv. You have no variable or parameter with this name, which causes the error "name blah.csv is not defined".

Assuming what you want is to open a file that is actually named blah.csv, you would pass that name as a string:

> > > amread('blah.csv')